# How to remove an item from a linked list in C using an index and a list as a parameter?

Tags: c

so im currently trying to create a function that will remove an item from a linked list using an index and a list as arguments. Heres what I got so far:

```
void* removeAtIndex(List* list_pointer, int index){
 
     // If linked list is empty 
       if (list_pointer == NULL) 
          return; 
      
       // Store head node 
       Node* temp = list_pointer->head;
      
        // If head needs to be removed 
        if (index == 0) 
        { 
            list_pointer->head= temp->next;   // Change head 
            free(temp);               // free old head 
            return; 
        } 
      
        // Find previous node of the node to be deleted 
        for (int i=0; temp!=NULL && i<index-1; i++) 
             temp = temp->next; 
      
        // If position is more than number of nodes 
        if (temp == NULL || temp->next == NULL) 
             return; 
      
        // Node temp->next is the node to be deleted 
        // Store pointer to the next of node to be deleted 
        struct Node *next = temp->next->next; 
      
        // Unlink the node from linked list 
        free(temp->next);  // Free memory 
      
        temp->next = next;  // Unlink the deleted node from list 
    };
```

So im having a problem with the `Node *next = temp->next->next;` Line. It gives me an "pointer to incomplete class type is not allowed". If I remove one next from the statement, the error goes away but that not what I want. This is how I define my node and List objects:

```
typedef struct {
    void* item;
    struct Node*  next;
}Node;

typedef struct {
    Node* head;
    Node* tail;
}List;
```

I would appreciate any help or advice, I am a bit stumped right now.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't define `struct Node`. You need to give the structure type a name in the `typedef`.

```
typedef struct Node {
    void* item;
    struct Node*  next;
} Node;
```

Comment: Oh, would I have to do the same for List?

Comment: You only need to do that for `struct Node` because it needs to reference itself before the `typedef` is defined. That's not the case for `List`.

Comment: Does my function look ok otherwise?

Comment: if you remove the last element, you need to change `list_pointer->tail` to point to the previous element. And if you remove the only element, both of them need to be changed to `NULL`.